# Is there a keyboard shortcut to go back to grid view?

Tags: itunes, keyboard-shortcuts

In `iTunes 9`, pressing return on any selected album or artist in the Grid View opens up the list view along with the album art on the left side. I want to go back to the Grid View using the keyboard. Is there a shortcut??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the official list of shortcuts for iTunes available [here](http://www.apple.com/itunes/how-to/shortcuts.html) there doesn't seem to be one. However, according to iTunes by looking at the shortcuts in the menu itself the following should work:

Grid View in OSX:
<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> (Garanteed)

Grid View in Windows:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>

Comment: yeah..that works! thanx gr8 tip!

Answer (score 1):

I used [Bettertouch Tool](http://boastr.de) to set a trackpad shortcut for <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> to make it more usable. You could also use [Jitouch](http://www.jitouch.com).